# What kind of flowering tree is this?

Tags: identification, trees, flowers, flowering

These flowering trees are found in Shenandoah Valley, Virginia. Can anyone identify what they are?
[image: Unidentified tree]
[image: Tree closeup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kwanzan Cherry Tree](http://hort.ufl.edu/database/documents/pdf/tree_fact_sheets/pruserb.pdf)....I have one!

Answer (score 5):

I think these are [Japanese cherries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_serrulata) of the group of [Cherry blossoms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_blossom).